# How find the distance between two objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocoding

Im using geocode. The idea is our partners can post products with an address. When they do so it fetches the latitude and longitude. Now when our customers go to buy that product they have to enter in a delivery address to tell us where to deliver the product. However if they delivery address is not within 20 miles of the product they are not allowed to get the product delivered.

Im getting an error message saying this "undefined method `latitude' for nil:NilClass"

Like I said the product.longitude, product.latitude is already set when the users are trying to order.

Not sure if it's because the order.delivery_address(lat, long) is not submitted into the database yet and its trying to check the distance. Here my code below

So My question is how can is how can i find the distance between the product address and order address and I want to show a alert message to the user if the distance between the two is over 20 miles.

```
 def create
        product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
        if current_user == product.user
            flash[:alert] = "You cannot purchase your own property"

        elsif current_user.stripe_id.blank? || current_user.phone_number.blank?
            flash[:alert] = " Please update your payment method and verify phone number please"
            return redirect_to payment_method_path
        elsif Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between([product.latitude, product.longitude], [@order.latitude, @order.longitude]) < 20
            flash[:alert] = "The delivery address you provided is outside the delivery zone. Please choose a different product."        
        else
            quantity = order_params[:quantity].to_i 

        @order = current_user.orders.build(order_params)
        @order.product = product
        @order.price = product.price
        @order.total = product.price * quantity + product.delivery_price

        # @order.save

        if @order.Waiting!
            if product.Request?
                flash[:notice] = "Request sent successfully... Sit back and relax while our licensed dispensary fulfil your order :)"
            else
                @order.Approved!
                flash[:notice] = "Your order is being filled and it will delivered shortly:)"
            end
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Our licensed dispensary cannot fulfil your order at this time :( "
        end

        end
        redirect_to product
    end
```

Comment: The error you have doesn't seem to be related with geocoding at all, it's more like `@order` instance variable is `nil`. So you probably need to show more code and rephrase this question to make correct answer possible.

Comment: updated comment sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

You set `@order` in the following line:

```
@order = current_user.orders.build(order_params)
```

But you try to call its `longitude` and `latitude` methods above this, before you even set `@order` variable. To simply fix this problem, you can move this line up, it can even be located at the beginning of `create` method, since it doesn't depend on `product` or anything like that:

```
def create
  @order = current_user.orders.build(order_params)
  # ...
end
```

Although, there are number of problems in your code, like method names starting with capital letters (you *can* do it, but you shouldn't, it's against the convention) or overall complexity of the method.

Answer (score 1):

You should move the business logic to the model where it belongs.

So lets start by creating a validation for the product distance:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord

  validates :product_is_within_range, 
    if: -> { product.present? } # prevents nil errors

  # our custom validation method
  def product_is_within_range
    errors.add(:base, "The delivery address you provided is outside the delivery zone. Please choose a different product.") if product_distance < 20
  end

  def product_distance
    Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(product.coordinates, self.coordinates)
  end
end
```

Then move the calculation of the total into the model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :calculate_total!, if: ->{ product && total.nil? }

  def calculate_total!
    self.total = product.price * self.quantity + product.delivery_price
  end
end
```

But then you still have to deal with the fact that the controller is very broken. For example:

```
if current_user == product.user
  flash[:alert] = "You cannot purchase your own property"
```

Should cause the method to bail. You´re not actually saving the record either. I would start over. Write failing tests for the different possible conditions (invalid parameters, valid parameters, user is owner etc) then write your controller code. Make sure you test each and every code branch.